# Array incrementing Javascript / node js / mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to gather data from a MongoDB with Node JS to draw a graph later.

My goal is to collect all entries by hour of the day. In my collection there is a "created_at" field which stores a Date Object.

I'm trying to store the data in an array with 24 slots like this:

```
// padding the array for each hour of the day
var hours = new Array(23);

// defaulting the value for each hour to 0
for(var i=0; i<hours.length; i++){
    hours[i] = 0;
}

db.collection.find({}, {"created_at": 1}, function(err, entry){
    if (err){ doSomething(); }
    else {
        entry.forEach(function(item, index){
                    // get hour of the day from the Date object
            h = item["created_at"].getHours();
            h = parseInt(h);
                    // store hour of the day and count it up
            hours[h]++;
            console.log("#%s: %s", index, h);
        });
    }
});

console.log(hours);
```

Now when I log `hours` I get the array with the default values. ie [0, 0, 0, 0 ... 0]
I'm certain that the database has correct values as the `console.log` in the inner function gets correct data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is one of concurrency: the collection's `.find` method is asynchronous.  So your `console.log` after the call to `.find` gets executed *before* the `entry.forEach` ever even executes.  Try moving the `console.log` into the body of the `else` clause, after the `forEach` (which is synchronous), and you should see the result you're looking for.

Going forward, you'll have to employ promises or something to get the results you want.

Comment: Your suspicion was correct and actually very logical. I'm still new to this asynchronous/callback stuff. Thanks

Comment: I've been doing JavaScript async programming for almost a year now, and I still get bit by it on a regular basis.  It's a slippery beast!